# SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1215 Cannot add foreign key constraint (SQL: alter table

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-8

i have three migrations

> 2022_09_20_021431_create_posts_table.php

```
 Schema::create('posts', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('title', 100);
        $table->text('body');
    });
```

> 2022_09_21_021455_create_category_posts_table.php

```
Schema::create('category_posts', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->unsignedBigInteger('category_id')->nullable();
        $table->unsignedBigInteger('post_id')->nullable();
        $table->primary(['category_id', 'post_id']);
        $table->foreign('category_id')->references('id')->on('categories')->onUpdate('cascade')->onDelete('cascade');
        $table->foreign('post_id')->references('id')->on('posts')->onUpdate('cascade')->onDelete('cascade');
    });
```

> 2022_09_28_021507_create_categories_table.php

```
 Schema::create('categories', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('name', 100);
    });
```

i found alotof solutions but not words with me i also made new project and still have the same error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Foreign keys and its referencing column data type should be same

so, change the `$table->increments('id');` to `$table->id();`

in tables `2022_09_20_021431_create_posts_table.php` and `2022_09_28_021507_create_categories_table.php`

Answer (score 0):

Categories table should be created first, before the category_posts. What you can do is you can try changing the name of the *"2022_09_28_021507_create_categories_table.php"* to have a date before *"2022_09_21_021455_create_category_posts_table.php"*.

For example change it to

> 2022_09_20_021507_create_categories_table.php

Comment: i already tried and still got same error
https://i.imgur.com/dT4VeVK.png

Comment: @KaremBarakat, maybe you can try separating the adding of foreign constraint? Like put this under the create table? 

Schema::table('category_posts', function($table) {
        $table->foreign('category_id')->references('id')->on('categories')->onUpdate('cascade')->onDelete('cascade');
        $table->foreign('post_id')->references('id')->on('posts')->onUpdate('cascade')->onDelete('cascade');
});

Comment: okay if i understand you right i deleted the two $table->foreign from schema and create new one (copy what u sent), i done that but still same error